# compiling error on c++, calcarea was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, function, compilation

I'm learning C++, and I'm doing this exercise that print the area of a triangle using functions, but there is an error when I try to compile "[Error] 'calcarea' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
double farea;

main(){
    float base, height;
    cout<<"Enter base of triangle: ";   cin>>base;
    cout<<"Enter height of triangle: "; cin>>height;
    cout<<endl;

    farea = calcarea(base,height);
    cout<<"The area of the triangle is: "<<farea;
    system("pause>nul");
}

double calcarea(float ba, float he){
    double area;

    area = (ba*he)/2;
    return area;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your compiler reads the code from head to bottom, and when it first encounters a symbol, in this case, `calcarea`, it checks if the symbol was declared. Since `calcarea` is only declared *after*, the compiler, at that time, is not aware of this symbol, hence, it's massage: *calcarea was not declared in this scope*

If you'll move the function to be before it's first call, this error will be resolved. Another way to resolve this issue, is to only declare the function before main, and define it after, meaning, you'll leave your function where it is, but add a line defining it before main: `double calcarea(float ba, float he);`

```
main(){
    float base, height;
    cout<<"Enter base of triangle: ";   cin>>base;
    cout<<"Enter height of triangle: "; cin>>height;
    cout<<endl;

    farea = calcarea(base,height); // here your compiler must already know what is calcarea, either by moving the definition, or only adding declaration 
    cout<<"The area of the triangle is: "<<farea;
    system("pause>nul");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is helping your right there. At the point you are calling `calcarea` it's not been declared yet. Move it or declare it before `main`.